# Congratulations, Yuval passed 200K!

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

Congratulations Yuval, you amaze me every day with patience, profound answers and constant fight to make people work harder, hinting them to solve own problems.

Thank you, reading your posts is always a pleasure.

Comment: Congrats Yuval for the great milestone! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I have seen points toll. It doesn't matter though, you can celebrate twice! You deserve it.

Comment: It seems that voting system is still flawed, points deduction is unfair and serial voting, well it makes sense only to users with small number of posts, in your case with more than 5k answers (and about 31k overall) people will encounter your posts with high probability (not just 1 in 6, topic-wise far more often), so it is rather hint to change limits to be based on number of posts.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The removal of the votes from the removed user(s) is unfortunate and I personally do not agree with the decision to not retain the votes. (although I of course have less information than the staff member(s) who made that decision) However, it has happened, and there is little we can do about it at this point.

Comment: As for the points deducted due to serial voting, this event usually occurs automatically, when the system has detected a suspicious voting pattern. It seems you have received a single vote on a large amount of different answers within 4 minutes. (see [here, on the day before the serial voting deduction, from 14:54 to 14:58](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus?tab=reputation&sort=post)) While I cannot see who  made those votes, it is possible that those votes were made by a single user, and if so, this would probably be automatically detected by the system.

Comment: So, I don't think the deduction due to serial voting is a conscious decision by a staff member, but a decision made by the system, without human intervention. However, I cannot be certain about this and I do not have more information than you regarding this. If you have any further concerns, I suggest you [contact the staff](https://cs.stackexchange.com/contact), as only they can see the votes of specific users, or the exact reason for the deduction event.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus [A user who voted a lot removed their account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328642). Normally, in such cases, the votes are retained. In this case, the votes were not retained. Stack Exchange only makes an exception when there's a good reason. This isn't about you: a lot of users on a lot of sites lost reputation points. You should console yourself by pondering that if Stack Exchange decided not to retain the votes, it means they thought those votes were not cast in good faith, so we (I lost points as well) didn't deserve the reputation.

Comment: Since many users have reached 200k rep and more on many sites across the network, I don't think developing conspiracy theories in the comment section of this question is called for.